# generating the graph of allowed moves in two-player games

Tags: machine-learning, topological-data-analysis

I recently came up with a method of constructing the graph of allowed moves in two-player boardgames like tic-tac-toe or chess, and I would like to turn this into a research project with a goal of aligning LLMs to play these games. I solved the problem for tic-tac-toe, and I'm working on extending the solution to chess, but since it involves both topological data analysis and self-supervised learning, I would like to work with someone experienced on this.

Has anyone heard of similar research, or knows researchers interested in the topic?